# Unable to Edit List Items - WSS3

Tags: list, wss-3.0

I'm experiencing a strange issue when trying to modify items in a list in WSS3.

My user is a site collection administrator and should have full permissions on the list. I can view the items, but when I change any of the properties and click OK, nothing happens. The page posts back but it doesn't save my changes.

I don't get any error messages and there is nothing in the logs.

I thought it was [this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rodneyviana/you-cannot-edit-list-or-document-library-items-on-existing-sharepoint-sites), but Rodney's tool reports that the issue isn't present on my site.

I'm at a total loss as to what's going on, any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I've carried out some more tests, I can edit the list items programmatically and also in Data Sheet view. The problem seems to just be with the standard edit form.

Comment: check your ULS log for critical issues that happens when you try to save, and post them here please

Comment: There are no specific errors generated when I try and save the list item unfortunately.

Comment: Are you using a stock editform or is this custom?

Comment: It's a standard form, it happens with all lists in the system.

Comment: Have you tried this with different browsers or on different machines?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with Firefox, IE and Chrome and on different machines. It's the same on all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but just had a similar issue on SharePoint 2013 and it was related to some custom javascript on a custom masterpage.  Even though the javascript was not having any errors, it was modifying the DOM ever so slightly as to affect how SharePoint sees the changes and saves them back.

Under the covers it looks like SharePoint builds up a hidden table of all the values of the list item, and using js, shuttles the values to a dynamically created form, and vice versa when saving.

If anyone has this issue, try reverting to a standard masterpage and if that fixes it, isolating all custom javascript.